# how can i add source node as child node in project?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, vb.net-2010

this is xml file that i created using LINQ.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <projects>
      <project id="2">
        <source id="2">
          <category>2</category>
        </source>
        <name>2</name>
        <category>2</category>
      </project>
    </projects>
```

i have used this following code.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("\\Demo.xml")
        Dim oDept = doc.Descendants().Elements("project").FirstOrDefault()

        Dim oEmp As New XElement("project")
        oEmp.Add(New XAttribute("id", 3))

        Dim src As New XElement("source")
        src.Add(New XAttribute("id", 3))
        src.Add(New XElement("category", 3))

        oEmp.Add(New XElement("name", 3))
        oEmp.Add(New XElement("category", 3))

        oEmp.Element("source").Add(src)
        doc.Save("\Demo.xml")
        MessageBox.Show("Added Succefully!")
 End Sub
```

i want to add src in oEmp  using this code.
Example : oEmp.Element("source").Add(src)

Comment: have you tried simple `oEmp.Add(src)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to add `XElement` as child of another `XElement` is simply call `.Add()` in the parent element passing child element as parameter. You already done that with `<name>` and `<category>` element here :

```
oEmp.Add(New XElement("name", 3))
oEmp.Add(New XElement("category", 3))
```

So it should be the same for `<source>` element :

```
Dim src As New XElement("source")
src.Add(New XAttribute("id", 3))
src.Add(New XElement("category", 3))
oEmp.Add(src)
```

Another thing, your code doesn't use `oEmp` element created in the end. If I understand what you're after correctly, you should add it as child of the root element (`<projects>`) this way before saving `doc` :

```
Dim root = doc.Root;
root.Add(oEmp);
```